# Memory allocation for a variant-typed token

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures, variant

I am making an interpreter for a custom programming language (concatenative, soft-typed) and for that purpose I have a central datatype `Token`. A Token can be of one of the many different types, either of scalar ones or vector ones. To minimize the amount of memory, I used a `union` first but then I could only use plain-old data structures in the union, so I resorted to a `struct` with all the fields (`long asInteger;`, `boost::shared_ptr<std::string> asString`, ...). That was of course a bad idea from a memory consumption viewpoint but it got the job done.

Since the `Token` datatype was almost 100 bytes long (making an array of  1,000,000 integers almost 100 megabytes for example), the original formulation showed massively inadequate. Today I revamped the implementation to dynamically allocate the memory needed for each element with copy semantics so that I got something similar to the `union` if I could use it with classes.

This is the new class definition:

```
class Token {
protected:
    TokenType tokenType_;

    template<class T>
    inline void copyToken(void * src, void * dst)
    {
      *static_cast<T*>(dst) = 
          *static_cast<T*>(src);
    };

    template<class T>
    inline void deleteValue()
    {
      delete static_cast<T*>(data);
    };

    void deleteData()
    {
        switch (tokenType_)
        {
            case T_INTEGER:   deleteValue<long>(); break; 
            case T_BOOL:      deleteValue<bool>(); break; 
            case T_FLOAT:     deleteValue<double>(); break;
            case T_STRING:    deleteValue<boost::shared_ptr<std::string>>(); break;  
            case T_ARRAY:     deleteValue<boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<Token>>>(); break;
            case T_HANDLE:    deleteValue<HandleData>(); break;
            default: ;
        }
    }

    void allocate(const TokenType tokenType)
    {       
        switch (tokenType)
        {
            case T_INTEGER:   data = new long; break; 
            case T_BOOL:      data = new bool;  break; 
            case T_FLOAT:     data = new double; break;
            case T_STRING:    data = new boost::shared_ptr<std::string>; break;  
            case T_ARRAY:     data = new boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<Token>>; break;
            case T_HANDLE:    data = new HandleData; break;
            default: data = NULL;
        }     
    };

    void * data;

public:

    void set_type(const TokenType tokenType)
    {
        deleteData();
        tokenType_ = tokenType;
        allocate(tokenType);
    };

    Token() : tokenType_ (T_EMPTY) { data = NULL; }; 

    Token(const TokenType tokenType) : tokenType_ (tokenType)  
    {
        allocate(tokenType);
    };

    Token(const Token& old_token)  
    {
        tokenType_ = old_token.tokenType_;
        allocate(old_token.tokenType_);
        switch (old_token.tokenType_)
        {
            case T_INTEGER:   copyToken<long>(old_token.data, data); break; 
            case T_BOOL:      copyToken<bool>(old_token.data, data); break; 
            case T_FLOAT:     copyToken<double>(old_token.data, data); break;
            case T_STRING:    copyToken<boost::shared_ptr<std::string>>(old_token.data, data); break; 
            case T_ARRAY:     copyToken<boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<Token>>>(old_token.data, data); break;
            case T_HANDLE:    copyToken<HandleData>(old_token.data, data); break;
            default: ;
        }       
    };

    template<class T>
    T& retreive()
    {
        return *static_cast<T*>(data);
    };

    template<class T>
    const T& retreive() const
    {
        return *static_cast<T*>(data);
    };

    void operator=(const Token &rhs) 
    {
        fileName = rhs.fileName;
        lineNum  = rhs.lineNum;
        set_type(rhs.tokenType_);
        switch (rhs.tokenType_)
        {
            case T_INTEGER:   copyToken<long>(rhs.data, data); break; 
            case T_BOOL:      copyToken<bool>(rhs.data, data); break; 
            case T_FLOAT:     copyToken<double>(rhs.data, data); break;
            case T_STRING:    copyToken<boost::shared_ptr<std::string>>(rhs.data, data); break; 
            case T_ARRAY:     copyToken<boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<Token>>>(rhs.data, data); break;
            case T_HANDLE:    copyToken<HandleData>(rhs.data, data); break;
            default: ;
        }       
    };

    ~Token()
    {
       deleteData();
    };
};
```

I would then create a token with

```
Token newToken(T_INTEGER);
newToken.retreive<long>() = 42;
```

Now the above code **works**, but is terribly slow (200% slower than the previous implementation with union). A profiler shows that almost half of the execution time is spent on `new` and `free()`. I have tried using placement new syntax on a `char data[50]` so that space for `Token` object is allocated on stack when applicable and only once in all cases and that speeds it up a lot but still not as fast as original (about 20% slower).

My question is: **How would I go about making this frequent allocation of small objects leaner and quicker?**

If this is usually done a whole different way, please advise me how to do it. I generally need a variant type that is robust and fast but not "smart" (automatic conversion, ...) as I have my own framework for that. Generally I would like to minimize the memory allocation cost while also minimizing the required memory.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Why don't you just use `boost:variant`? Also, C++11 relaxes the rules on `union`.

Comment: The point is, I don't want to use `union`because the memory consumption is enormous. As for the `boost::variant`, I don't really know, will take a look at it.

Comment: If the `boost:variant` class does not suits you, I would consider to use some inheritance to avoid switching on types.

Comment: Actually, `boost::variant` seems to be just the solution I am looking for! I don't know why I overlooked it the last time I checked it. You can post it as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years old, and it seems you found your answer but you never posted it so I will explain some solutions if anyone stumbles on this post (like I did).

## **Union**

Yes, the same data structure that you ended up avoiding could have been used. This would reduce the amount of data enormously. Say you have these four types: `bool`, `int`, `float`, and a `double`. The size of the union will always be the largest which isn't the best, but it's better than the size of *all* the elements. Now, you said "*...I could only use plain-old data structures in the union...*" which is true but it can take pointers to non-generic types. This can fix most of your memory problems but if you use pointers you will have to use `new` and `delete` so you will still run slower because of these. The other downside to using a union would be that you have to keep track of the type that is being used.

### Boost::variant

If you have access to the boost library then I would definitely go with this. I don't think it saves as much memory as a union, but it save a whole lot more than holding all the values. This also allows for non-generic types. Also, you don't have to keep track of which type is being used. All you have to keep track of is the order you wrote the types.

I would say go with the **Boost::variant** but be possible with the union.